# SQL - How do I calculate the sum only for distinct rows of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with covid data containing a lot of different data entries. Each row has the Country, Continent, Population and different data which is not relevant for this.
I want to simply calculate the population per CONTINENT, but I can't figure out how.

| Continent | Country | Population | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | Bulgaria | 690.000 |  |
| Europe | Bulgaria | 690.000 |  |
| Europe | Bulgaria | 690.000 |  |
| America | Brazil | 212.000.000 |  |
| America | Brazil | 212.000.000 |  |
| America | Brazil | 212.000.000 |  |
| America | Brazil | 212.000.000 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

```
SELECT distinct country, continent, SUM(population) as TotalPopulation
FROM PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths
GROUP by continent
```

This is what I tried before but it produces an error: Column 'PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths.location' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

And this code snippet sums up each row of a country. Therefore the continent populations are ridiculously high.

```
SELECT continent, SUM(population) as TotalPopulation
From PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths
GROUP by continent
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. What you actually want here, however, is a windowed `SUM`; so there should be no `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: Also note that syntax like `DatabaseName..ObjectName` is *not* recommended. Don't rely on the default schema, be explicit and define the schema you want. Also, as you're only querying one table, do you need to use 3 part naming? Why not connect to the `PortfolioProject` database and then just include the schema and table (presumably `dbo.CovidDeaths`).

Comment: Remove the duplicate rows - that is the source of your problem. Alternatively, you remove the duplicates BEFORE you sum, not AFTER.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the help! I wasn't aware that PortfolioProject.dbo.CovidDeaths was the recommended way of putting it.
And I didn't really understand what you mean with "do you need to use 3 part naming?"

Comment: 3 part naming means literally what it sounds like, using 3 parts for the name; in this case database name, schema name, object name. Do you really need the database name? Why are you not connected to the database `PortfolioProject`?

Comment: Thanks! I changed the naming into `FROM PortfolioProject.dbo.CovidDeaths` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data probably also contains a column that indicates when the population total was reported.

In that case you'd want the latest reported population totals for the countries.

So let's assume there's such a date column named "ReportedAt"

Then you can use ROW_NUMBER to get the latest record per country.
And then aggregate for the continent.

```
SELECT continent, SUM(population) AS TotalPopulation
FROM
(
  SELECT country, continent, population
  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY ReportedAt DESC) 
  FROM PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths
) q
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY continent;
```

Comment: Good spot. Though just to be extra cautious, you may want to partition by continent as well. Otherwise, the results would drop countries that appeared under multiple continents for some reason (like a typo).

Comment: @SOS Well, but then those populations would be counted to much? So I'll keep my solution as is. The OP also sees your comment, so he can check if that's needed or not. Thanks for warning.

Comment: No, it's counting the data as it actually exists.  If the base data is corrupted, that's a different problem altogether. One that needs to be solved, yes, but it's not the job of this query to do that IMO. So respectfully, I disagree with omitting it, but we'll agree to disagree (-:

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't have a column with information of ReportedAt, however it is also not necessary. The population is the same for every row of the partition.
Finally, this was the solution which made my query work:
`SELECT continent, SUM(population) AS TotalPopulation`
`FROM`
`(` 
 `SELECT location, continent, population`
 `, rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY location)`
 `FROM PortfolioProject.dbo.CovidDeaths`
`) q`
`WHERE rn = 1 AND continent IS NOT NULL`
`GROUP BY continent`

However,  I am still wondering, what the letter "q"  is doing?

Comment: In Sql Server a sub-query is required to have an alias name. 'q' is just the first letter of the word 'query'